# What is gear bicycle is it useful in countryside?

Tags: gears

I want to know about multi gear cycle. My area is a flat surface. What's the major use of geared one vs. single speed bicycle?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Bicycles Stack Exchange. It is unclear what you are asking. Are you considering a multi gear cycle vs a single speed? If so, please tell us about your environment - hilly or flat, types of roads or trails etc.

Comment: Hi..Yes i want to know about multi gear cycle.My area is a flat surface.What's the major use of geared one vs.Normal bicycle?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You can edit your question as well as replying with a comment. Also, by 'mono suspension' do you actually mean 'single gear'?

Comment: I don't know about it,here mono suspension means a single shock observer in my bicycle.I plan to fix a gear for my cycle in shops more than 20 gears variety available.what's use of that?

Comment: I'd be _very_ surprised if fitting gears to your bike was cheaper than just buying a new bike. You'll need a lot of new parts and they might not even be compatible with your existing frame. Of course, you need to buy less parts than a whole new bike but manufacturers get a big discount on parts by ordering thousands and thousands of them, but you'll just be ordering one of each.

Answer (score 3):

Modern multi geared bicycles allow the rider to be more efficient when riding at different speeds on different inclines. Lower ratio gears also allow riding up steep slopes that would be impossible using gear ratios that are suitable for riding on flat surfaces.

In other words, multiple gears make riding *much* easier for most riders.

Converting a single speed bicycle to multi gear with a derailleur is usually problematic and not cost-effective. The rear wheel has to be replaced, and the frame may lack attachment points for the derailleur and cables. It is better to purchase a bicycle that is designed for and comes with a multi gear drivetrain.

Comment: Wind makes a significant difference to required effort. Even if you only ride on very flat  ground you need gears in some (My average speed can go down to 12km/h on the flat, and over 30km/h, on the same stretch of road in the same direction depending on the day)